# Opening xib crashes xcode and old xcode is not opening the nib in old interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm getting following crash report when opening the xib file in Xcode.

**Crash Report:**

```
Process:         Xcode [5891]
Path:            /Xcode4/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.0 (4.0)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-540000~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [89]

Date/Time:       2010-11-13 13:03:49.931 +0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          1223931 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           110
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1068654 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   20
Anonymous UUID:                      EFCCCE57-6AC6-49DC-8818-B592EA41E40D

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
Encountered multiple assertions. First assertion was:
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-240/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:122
Details:  Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (5897) failed to launch and exited with status 10. Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.
Function: NSDistantObject<IBCocoaTouchToolProtocol> *IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x2000205a0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001006a1c2d -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001000218b0 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000100021936 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000117073c11 IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x0000000117073736 IBInstallAppPatches (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x00000001170755b0 IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000011706e6cd IBReleaseIsWildcat (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000011706e720 IBReleaseIsWildcat (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000011706e769 IBReleaseIsWildcat (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000011706902d IBReplaceClassNamePrefixWith (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 10  0x0000000117068b13 IBReplaceClassNamePrefixWith (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 11  0x0000000117074890 IBBuildMarshalledDescriptionOfDocument (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 12  0x0000000117075177 IBBuildMarshalledDescriptionOfObject (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 13  0x000000011709eb08 IBIsContainedTabBarItem (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 14  0x000000011709e9e6 IBIsContainedTabBarItem (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 15  0x000000011709f2c6 IBIsContainedTabBarItem (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 16  0x00007fff836961d5 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:topView:] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff83695a0e -[NSView displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:] (in AppKit)
 18  0x0000000116960253 -[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderViewRect:intoCoreGraphicsContext:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x000000011696074a __39-[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderContent]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x00000001002b4cbb -[NSGraphicsContext(DVTNSGraphicsContextAdditions) dvt_drawBlockByPreservingState:] (in DVTKit)
 21  0x00000001169581c8 -[NSGraphicsContext(IBGraphicsContextsAdditions) temporarilyMakeCurrentAndDoOperationPerservingState:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x0000000116960604 -[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderContent] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x000000011695a1d9 -[IBViewRenderer renderViewImage] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x000000011695985c -[IBViewRasterizer image] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x00000001169597ae +[IBViewRasterizer imageOfView:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26  0x000000011709dcad IBIsContainedTabBarItem (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 27  0x000000011709f3d3 IBIsContainedTabBarItem (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 28  0x00007fff8360e081 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x00007fff8360ccf4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff8360b3c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 37  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 38  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 39  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 40  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 41  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 42  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 43  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 44  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 45  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 46  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 47  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 48  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 49  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 50  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 51  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 52  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 53  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 54  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 55  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 56  0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 57  0x00007fff8360aee8 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 58  0x00007fff8360779a -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] (in AppKit)
 59  0x00007fff83580ff6 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 60  0x00007fff8357bea2 _handleWindowNeedsDisplay (in AppKit)
 61  0x00007fff887d8077 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 62  0x00007fff887b3ef4 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 63  0x00007fff887b384f CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 64  0x00007fff8711891a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 65  0x00007fff8711867d ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 66  0x00007fff871185d8 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 67  0x00007fff8355129e _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 68  0x00007fff83550bed -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 69  0x00007fff835168d3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 70  0x00007fff8350f5f8 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 71  0x0000000100000eec

abort() called
objc[5891]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff825b13d6 __kill + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff82651972 abort + 83
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit            0x00000001006a152e __53+[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:]_block_invoke_0 + 0
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x00000001000218b0 _DVTAssertionHandler + 330
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x0000000100021936 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 110
5   ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117073c11 IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool + 1161
6   ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117073736 IBInstallAppPatches + 2038
7   ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x00000001170755b0 IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext + 70
8   ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706e6cd IBReleaseIsWildcat + 1082
9   ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706e720 IBReleaseIsWildcat + 1165
10  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706e769 IBReleaseIsWildcat + 1238
11  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706902d IBReplaceClassNamePrefixWith + 1905
12  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117068b13 IBReplaceClassNamePrefixWith + 599
13  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117074890 IBBuildMarshalledDescriptionOfDocument + 2503
14  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117075177 IBBuildMarshalledDescriptionOfObject + 174
15  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709eb08 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 37518
16  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709e9e6 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 37228
17  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709f2c6 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 39500
18  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff836961d5 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:topView:] + 1349
19  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83695a0e -[NSView displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:] + 461
20  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000116960253 -[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderViewRect:intoCoreGraphicsContext:] + 131
21  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011696074a __39-[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderContent]_block_invoke_0 + 211
22  com.apple.dt.DVTKit            0x00000001002b4cbb -[NSGraphicsContext(DVTNSGraphicsContextAdditions) dvt_drawBlockByPreservingState:] + 34
23  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001169581c8 -[NSGraphicsContext(IBGraphicsContextsAdditions) temporarilyMakeCurrentAndDoOperationPerservingState:] + 72
24  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000116960604 -[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderContent] + 849
25  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011695a1d9 -[IBViewRenderer renderViewImage] + 252
26  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011695985c -[IBViewRasterizer image] + 82
27  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001169597ae +[IBViewRasterizer imageOfView:] + 82
28  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709dcad IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 33843
29  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709f3d3 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 39769
30  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360e081 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3390
31  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360ccf4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1325
32  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
33  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
34  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
35  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
36  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
37  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
38  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
39  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
40  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
41  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
42  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
43  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
44  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
45  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
46  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
47  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
48  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
49  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
50  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
51  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
52  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
53  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
54  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
55  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
56  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
57  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
58  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360b3c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 767
59  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360aee8 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 254
60  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360779a -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2683
61  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83580ff6 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 969
62  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8357bea2 _handleWindowNeedsDisplay + 678
63  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887d8077 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 519
64  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887b3ef4 __CFRunLoopRun + 468
65  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887b384f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
66  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8711891a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
67  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8711867d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 148
68  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff871185d8 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
69  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8355129e _DPSNextEvent + 708
70  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83550bed -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
71  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8378bed3 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 442
72  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83789a61 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 129
73  com.apple.dt.IDEKit            0x00000001006a0bbd -[IDE_IBDetailedAlert runModal] + 72
74  com.apple.dt.IDEKit            0x00000001006a16c7 __53+[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:]_block_invoke_018 + 132
75  com.apple.dt.IDEKit            0x00000001006a14e7 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:] + 318
76  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x00000001000218b0 _DVTAssertionHandler + 330
77  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x0000000100021936 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 110
78  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117073c11 IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool + 1161
79  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117073736 IBInstallAppPatches + 2038
80  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x00000001170755b0 IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext + 70
81  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706e6cd IBReleaseIsWildcat + 1082
82  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706e720 IBReleaseIsWildcat + 1165
83  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706e769 IBReleaseIsWildcat + 1238
84  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011706902d IBReplaceClassNamePrefixWith + 1905
85  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117068b13 IBReplaceClassNamePrefixWith + 599
86  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117074890 IBBuildMarshalledDescriptionOfDocument + 2503
87  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000117075177 IBBuildMarshalledDescriptionOfObject + 174
88  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709eb08 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 37518
89  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709e9e6 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 37228
90  ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709f2c6 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 39500
91  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff836961d5 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:topView:] + 1349
92  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83695a0e -[NSView displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:] + 461
93  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000116960253 -[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderViewRect:intoCoreGraphicsContext:] + 131
94  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011696074a __39-[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderContent]_block_invoke_0 + 211
95  com.apple.dt.DVTKit            0x00000001002b4cbb -[NSGraphicsContext(DVTNSGraphicsContextAdditions) dvt_drawBlockByPreservingState:] + 34
96  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001169581c8 -[NSGraphicsContext(IBGraphicsContextsAdditions) temporarilyMakeCurrentAndDoOperationPerservingState:] + 72
97  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000116960604 -[IBCoreGraphicsRenderer renderContent] + 849
98  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011695a1d9 -[IBViewRenderer renderViewImage] + 252
99  ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011695985c -[IBViewRasterizer image] + 82
100 ....IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001169597ae +[IBViewRasterizer imageOfView:] + 82
101 ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709dcad IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 33843
102 ...uilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011709f3d3 IBIsContainedTabBarItem + 39769
103 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360e081 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3390
104 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360ccf4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1325
105 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
106 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
107 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
108 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
109 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
110 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360d05e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
111 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360b3c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 767
112 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
113 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
114 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
115 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
116 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
117 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
118 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
119 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
120 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
121 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
122 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
123 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
124 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
125 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
126 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
127 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
128 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
129 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
130 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
131 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360c292 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
132 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360aee8 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 254
133 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8360779a -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2683
134 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83580ff6 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 969
135 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8357bea2 _handleWindowNeedsDisplay + 678
136 com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887d8077 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 519
137 com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887b3ef4 __CFRunLoopRun + 468
138 com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887b384f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
139 com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8711891a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
140 com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8711867d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 148
141 com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff871185d8 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
142 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8355129e _DPSNextEvent + 708
143 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff83550bed -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
144 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff835168d3 -[NSApplication run] + 395
145 com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8350f5f8 NSApplicationMain + 364
146 com.apple.dt.Xcode             0x0000000100000eec 0x100000000 + 3820

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8257c08a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8257df5d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8257dc34 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8257d75e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8257d088 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8257cf25 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff825632fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8256396d mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887b43c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff887b384f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8561c4c3 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 297
5   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8559ce8d __NSThread__main__ + 1429
6   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8259c456 _pthread_start + 331
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00007fff8259c309 thread_start + 13
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing everything in XCode, IB and cleaning all build files. Also delete the app from the simulator. You might even consider restarting the computer.

Make sure that youre not linking to any non existent objects inside the nib file and that all defined class types in the nib exist.